# Bazel: prevent android_binary from creating new jni layer

Tags: android, android-ndk, bazel

I have an Android app that uses a java API that wraps a C native lib. I have this working: android_binary (name: "MyLibTest") depends on the API, which is built as android_library (name: "MyLibAndroid") with a dependency on the jni layer (cc_library, name: "mylib_jni"), which depends on the wrapped C lib (cc_library, name "mylib").

I want MyLibAndroid to be responsible for loading the native code using System.loadLibrary("mylib_jni"). The problem is that Bazel is creating a native library for my android_binary app, so instead I have to put System.loadLibrary("MyLibTest") in my app code.

Is there a way to tell Bazel to associate the native jni lib with the android_library rather than the android_binary?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that bazel names the .so the same as the android_binary is that bazel links all the cc_library rules in the dependencies of the android_binary into a single .so file, so it doesn't really work to pick one of the names of the cc_library rules.

One way to handle this is to read the file named `nativedeps` that Bazel puts at the root of the apk. It will contain the name of the .so file that bazel linked, so you don't have to hardcode the name in your library code.